# Curbing excessive whitespace in front of code

Tags: discussion, code-formatting

Quite often, a question is asked with excessive whitespace in front of all the code, like this:

```
        var a = 1;
        var b = 3;
        if(a > 0) {
          b--;
          alert(b);
        }
```

Within 10 minutes, I was able to screenshot not [one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cZ6zO.png), not [two](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8IIla.png), but [three](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J1I14.png) examples of this sort of thing happening. These were all corrected through editing, but it begs the question: *Why does this happen so often?*

What is even more curious is that the code formatting button and the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> shortcut *physically do not let you* format code with excess whitespace like this: The selected code toggles between an indent of zero to four spaces.

So my questions are:

- How do users manage to indent code with a ridiculous amount of spaces when pasting or writing code into their question?
- And more importantly, ***how can we reduce occurrences like these?***

Is some sort of a 'excessive whitespace' warning tooltip needed?

Comment: People copy and paste already indented code from their editor, is why. Experienced editors simply select the block and hit `CTRL-K` an appropriate number of times to unindent.

Comment: You cannot reliably detect occurrences like these. It is, as you note, always dealt with swiftly, just like all the other usual mistakes, like *thanks* and *looking forward to your answers*, etc. There is little point in trying to battle this, it is *not* a big problem.

Comment: @MartijnPieters `Ctrl-K` won't clean all the extra space if your starting indentation is not a multiple of 4.

Comment: _Why does this happen so often?_ Because people are apparently unable to look at the preview when posting a question (or answer as well). What you should do, of course, is downvote the post and tell the OP to fix their formatting. If it's bad enough to severely harm readability I'd also closevote with the off-topic/MCVE reason, as a mangled heap of code is not a sufficient example. While this does nothing to improve formatting for new users, it hopefully helps to get the offending users to more carefully format their code - or get them questionbanned if they don't learn.

Comment: @Louis: nope, at which point I'd use a local editor to remove the 1-3 extra spaces in there real quick. Those are more of an exception however.

Comment: People are unfamiliar with the SO-specific `Ctrl+K` shortcut. I always wondered why they never implemented indentation with the standard `Tab`/`Shift+Tab` keys.

Comment: You should know by now that programmers are lazy people.

Comment: There should really be a reminder near the editor about Ctrl-K, I have been around here awhile and didn't know about it. I have had this issue where my code will be over-indented and I've always just manually remove the white space. -_- Very annoying.

Comment: Some languages are whitespace-sensitive and parse errors depend on the number of tabs and spaces on each line. It's important to NOT automatically remove whitespace from code.

Comment: Would it be particularly difficult to implement Tab/Shift+Tab for indent/unindent?

Comment: @MartijnPieters I would think it would be possible to detect when an entire code block has a large amount of indentation and show the poster one of those red message bubbles suggesting the Ctrl+K option.

Comment: It is more annoying when they don't even attempt to format the code!

Comment: It would be great if the code tidy function present in the code editor would auto run on code blocks when a post is submitted...

Comment: @MartijnPieters what is this `CTRL-K` you speak of? I tried `Ctrl` + `Shift` + `K` to no avail.

Comment: @JLRishe: because there are a) legitimate uses of using extra indentation (breaking up a correctly indented codeblock with interspersed paragraphs) and b) Markdown bullets and blockquotes also use indentation, so detecting when a codeblock contains extra indentation is more complicated and requires a full parse. I simply don't think it is worth the effort, because it is not a big problem.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I have no idea how much work it would involve or whether it's worth doing. I was just responding to your statement that "You cannot reliably detect occurrences like these." I think they can be be detected 95-99% of the time by identifying (a) a code block where (b) all lines have more than 4 leading spaces. And using a pop-up bubble wouldn't force anything on the poster, so that solves the issue of false positives. I think there's a possible solution; whether it's worth doing is another matter.

Comment: Sloth. That is why.

Comment: @JonathanDrapeau: Speak for yourself. Good programmers are diligent and thoughtful people who consider all the cases and needs.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit You are correct.

Comment: @AndrewC what language is harmed if **every** block of code in a post had **identical** whitespace removed from the start of **every** line in the post?  (Identical, in that ` ` and ` ` are never the same)

Comment: Is it so bad when the code has extra indentation? Should I remove indentation from my code when posting it? I say meh. What matters is the indentation inside the code, not before it.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: The Markdown previewer already does a full parse on just about every keypress anyway. It also has a bunch of convenient hooks for adding extra features, so a code indentation checker should be easy enough to write. I could see about implementing one as a user script, just as a proof of concept.

Comment: @Yakk I can write you a code block that compiles where each line starts with 5 spaces, and then some continue with a further three spaces, and some continue with a tab. If you remove 4 spaces (or 5 spaces) from the start of each line of that, they no longer line up at the 8-space tabstop, and you get a parse error. It's worse than you thought - it could introduce new parse errors that answerers would respond to! The golden rule is, in a whitespace-sensitive language, DO NOT automatically edit the whitespace.

Comment: @AndrewC which specific language are you talking about?  That is all I  asked.

Comment: @Yakk Python and Haskell have tabstops at 8 so can be affected by adding or removing spaces, even uniformly, because you can change whether you're hitting a tabstop. Possibly Occam and YaML too, I don't know. If the language is whitespace sensitive and allows tabs, it has to have a rule about what they mean. There's no particular reason that these rules have to be uniform.

Comment: Is there an opposite of the Ctrl-K shortcut that does the reverse and adds spaces to indent the selected text?

Comment: @CharlieKilian Ctrl-K toggles uniform initial 4-spaces. I've surmised from others's comments that it decides which way to go based on whether there are already uniformly 4 initial spaces. If that's the case then pressing it twice on code with 8 initial spaces would delete them all, but a third or fifth time would reintroduce 4.

Comment: @Yakk: You also forgot the whitespace language.  Removing identical whitespace from each line would definitely harm that!

Comment: @AndrewC I don’t know about Haskell but Python most definitely does *not* have tabstops at 8. Your editor might.

Comment: @SimonWright  I'm no Python expert, but the [Python 2 specs](https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/indentation.html) and [Python 3 specs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#indentation) appear to disagree with you by explaining that tabs are replaced by spaces to a multiple of 8. It is therefore slightly risky to have your tabstops in your editor set at anything other than 8 unless you have it set to automatically convert spaces to tabs or visa-versa for you.

Comment: @AndrewC I see what you mean. I’m an Emacs user, & I’m used to keyboard TAB meaning "indent to appropriate level using the appropriate number of spaces", so I don’t see TAB characters in any code I write (excepting Makefiles, of course). What I do find annoying is code (such as FreeRTOS) which wants you to set tabstops in your editor to something other than 8. Anyway, I digress.

Comment: @SimonWright Summary: python has  tabstops at 8 but your editor might not. I agree that having your editor convert tabs to spaces is the best all round for relevant-whitespace languages. I disagree with automatically removing a consistent number of spaces from the beginning of lines in stack overflow because it can introduce syntax errors that weren't there before by artificially tumbling someone's silly jenga tower of mixed tabs and spaces.

Answer (score 24):

As Martijn mentions in the [comments](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/282912/curbing-excessive-whitespace-in-front-of-code#comment139108_282912), this is a result of pasting existing code in the asker's editor into the question. This is even more likely if the code being pasted is buried even slightly into a larger program.

This type of error can be corrected by highlighting the code block while editing, and using the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> shortcut to unindent the code. This will work if the spacing is a multiple of 4.

Comment: Alternatively, if the code is javascript, you can paste it in a snippet, unident the first line and click tidy.

Comment: All this time, I never knew about the CTRL-K shortcut.  Argh, how much time have I wasted manually changing each line!!

Comment: I think one reason peoples often do not use properly the _Code Sample_ command (either by clicking on it or through `Ctrl+K`) is because it works differently depending if there was a selection or not. Many code editors allow you to indent/unident the _current_ line. The SO editor does not. You have to select _at least one whole line_ first. Maybe an indent/unindent button might have been a better choice there ?

Comment: I've been using this site for two years and just found out about CTRL-K by reading this question/answer. I've been manually de-indenting my code one line at a time, and I'm not surprised new users won't go to all that effort. If we want new users to use that shortcut, we should probably document it a lot better.

Comment: @Edward Or have a button for it. IMHO, a keyboard shortcut should just be a... shortcut. Not the only way of doing something. I think I had seen it mentioned before, but forgot what the key combination was before I had a chance to use it.

Comment: Do people not have text editors anymore? In vim it's trivial to change any code to the format required for SO, and I guess it should be simple in any other editor worth using. Does the vast majority of users actually type all their code directly in the SO textbox? I only do so for oneliners and small answer snippets, everything more complex is written in vim. And @RetoKoradi of course there is a button for that functionality, it's not just a keyboard shortcut.

Comment: @RetoKoradi There is a button for it. Ctrl + K is just the shortcut for "Code Sample".

Answer (score 10):

> And more importantly, how can we reduce occurrences like these?

Why don't we add some intelligence to the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> command? It is possible to calculate the smallest number of leading whitespace in the selected code, eliminate that many from all lines, then add 4 leading spaces to each line.

### Test

```js
function ctrlk() {
  var lines = document.getElementById("code").value.replace(/\t/g, "    ").split(/^/m),
    lws = Number.MAX_VALUE,
    i;
  for (i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
    if (lines[i].length) {
      lws = Math.min(lws, lines[i].match(/^ */)[0].length);
    }
  }
  for (i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
    lines[i] = lws < 4 ? ("    ".substr(0, 4 - lws) + lines[i]) : lines[i].substr(lws);
  }
  document.getElementById("code").value = lines.join("");
}
```

```css
textarea {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
  height: 10em;
}
input[type=button] {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<textarea id="code">
        var a = 1;
        var b = 3;
        if(a > 0) {
          b--;
          alert(b);
        }
</textarea>
<input type="button" onclick="ctrlk()" value="Toggle Code Sample">
```

Note: not tested against edge cases.

Comment: I use code which requires at least one leading space on each line. Please don't do that.

Comment: @BillWoodger can you please post an example?

Comment: `       MOVE example-identifier-1 TO example-identifier-2`. ` OPTION COPY`. The first is COBOL the second is DFSORT/SyncSort. Ah, turned out to be trickier than I thought, as here in the comments even within the backticks the leading spaces are being eaten :-) Thats seven on the first, and one on the second.

Comment: Here's a random link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27777666/get-field-names-while-running-program . You only see three spaces, because the others are already there. This is less handy with the SORT examples, where you copy from the displayed code...

Comment: Snippet duly eats three/one of required spaces :-)

Comment: The assumption that whitespace is only ever for human readability is simply false. Not all languages are based on the curly bace semicolon model of syntax.

Answer (score 0):

To build on [@Salman A's idea of formatting](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/283014/2770309), there's already language detection occurring in code blocks. Perhaps make some of the subsequent formatting not just highlighting but whitespace "fixing" or an option (button?) to do so.

ex `LANG_X` detected: offer to/do beautify for `LANG_X` rules.

For user's hair, any action taken automatically might need to be done only once in the event the user **wants** the spacing as they put.

Downside is the need for individual language comprehension. But then, that's [the issue @AndrewC brought up](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/283014/2770309).

Answer (score 0):

After reading all the comments and answers, I'm surprised no one has mentioned the <kbd>{}</kbd> button in the editor. Highlight and click. That's what I use